# Canadian to Cuba and Cayman

Tags: canadian-citizens, cuba, cayman-islands

Can I travel from Cuba to Grand Cayman and enter the Caymans using my birth certificate instead of my passports?

Answer (score 2):

According to http://www.immigration.gov.ky/portal/page/portal/immhome/visitinghere/entryrequirements no, to enter the Cayman Islands a passport or some other valid document establishing your identity and nationality or place of permanent residence is required. This should be valid beyond the date of your return ticket.